# PySpark SQL Dataframe identify and store consecutive matching value rows incrementally

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I was wondering if I could store information of a boolean column in a pyspark dataframe that has consecutive true and false values into another column showing the "Occurrence #" of the consecutive TRUE values.

| Bool Column I have | Column I want to create |
| --- | --- |
| True | 1 |
| True | 1 |
| True | 1 |
| True | 1 |
| False | 0 |
| False | 0 |
| True | 2 |
| True | 2 |
| False | 0 |
| True | 3 |
| True | 3 |

I would like the TRUE rows to increment and FALSE to stay at 0.
I am fairly new to pyspark and have only been able to succeed at doing this by converting to a pandas dataframe. If you could give me a pyspark solution or guidance this would be much appreciated.

The data is ordered by a data column not pictured in the table above.

Comment: spark dataframes are unordered. There is no concept of 'consecutive' unless you have a column to order by.

Comment: Thank you for your comment, I should have mentioned that the values are ordered by a timestamp column.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a helper column `begin` as shown below, and do a rolling sum using window function:

Sample dataframe:

```
df.show()
+---+-----+
| ts|  col|
+---+-----+
|  0| true|
|  1| true|
|  2| true|
|  3| true|
|  4|false|
|  5|false|
|  6| true|
|  7| true|
|  8|false|
|  9| true|
| 10| true|
+---+-----+
```

Code:

```
w = Window.orderBy('ts')
df2 = df.withColumn(
    'begin', 
    F.coalesce(
        (F.lag('col').over(w) != F.col('col')) & F.col('col'), 
        F.lit(True)    # take care of first row where lag is null
    ).cast('int')
).withColumn(
    'newcol', 
    F.when(
        F.col('col'), 
        F.sum('begin').over(w)
    ).otherwise(0)
)

df2.show()
+---+-----+-----+------+
| ts|  col|begin|newcol|
+---+-----+-----+------+
|  0| true|    1|     1|
|  1| true|    0|     1|
|  2| true|    0|     1|
|  3| true|    0|     1|
|  4|false|    0|     0|
|  5|false|    0|     0|
|  6| true|    1|     2|
|  7| true|    0|     2|
|  8|false|    0|     0|
|  9| true|    1|     3|
| 10| true|    0|     3|
+---+-----+-----+------+
```